# Need to add form data to CSV file but PHP Array from input values being recognised as string

Tags: php, arrays, forms, csv

I am trying to convert the values from an HTML form to a PHP array and from that into a new CSV row. I haven't had much success despite searching for hours. Here is where I am right now:

```
$fields = empty($_POST["wrdlGuess"]) ? 'null' : $_POST["wrdlGuess"];
$fh = fopen("test.csv", "a");
$delimiter = '|';
foreach ($fields as $field) {
   fputcsv($fh, $field, $delimiter);
};
```

This is the html form I have:

```
<form action="add_to_csv.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="wrdlGuess[]" value="null1">
    <input type="text" name="wrdlGuess[]" value="null2">
    <input type="text" name="wrdlGuess[]" value="null3">
    <input type="text" name="wrdlGuess[]" value="null4">
    <input type="text" name="wrdlGuess[]" value="null5">
    <input type="text" name="wrdlGuess[]" value="null6">
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Currently this is returning an error saying "Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given in... [file path]". Are all the values being concatenated into a single string, which needs splitting back up?

"add_to_csv.php" is the file that contains the form, so when it is submitted it sends the data to itself. Perhaps it's better practice to use a separate file?

I'm certain this is child's play and I'm just not on the ball enough to get my head around it. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks for reading!

Comment: The issue is of course that $_POST["wrdlGuess"]` is an array not a scalar

Comment: Do you expect the 6 occurances to be placed in one row in the `.csv` or do you expect 6 lines in the `.cvs`

Comment: A single row with 6 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a new array from the inputs and then use that in the `fputcsv()`

```
foreach ($_POST["wrdlGuess"] as $guess) {
    $guesses[] = $guess;
}
fputcsv($fh, $guesses, $delimiter);
```

Comment: Now I'm getting
• Undefined array key "wrdlGuess
• foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given
• Undefined variable $guesses
• Uncaught TypeError: fputcsv(): Argument #2 ($fields) must be of type array, null given

Comment: Try adding a `var_export($_POST);` to see whats actually in the $_POST Array

Comment: `array ( 'wrdlGuess' => array ( 0 => 'seryrewj', 1 => 'rtyhe6', 2 => 'rdgfh6', 3 => '67567uetyhj', 4 => '56yrthe6', 5 => 'gfhdhdj', ), )` so the array is definitely being populated by the input fields.

Comment: Works here just fine, did you do anything with $_POST before getting to this code

Comment: Example without the csv output https://3v4l.org/uip6v